# Does the Rinnegan eye put more strain on the user?

Tags: naruto

In the anime, it is shown that over usage of Byakugan and Sharingan eyes will cause the user to strain. Does that happen with a Rinnegan user?

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere that it does.

Comment: In Naruto, Byakugan and Sharingan strain are slightly different though. Byakugan strain is just temporary while Sharingan users actually start going (permanently) blind from too much usage. I'm pretty sure Rinnegan causes no strain as people like Pain were constantly using it. On the other hand, people like Tobi turned off his Sharingan quite often.

Comment: Only overuse of Mangekyu leads to blindness I think. Normal Sharingan does not.

Answer (score 3):

They never mention strain of the Rinnegan in the manga so the following is conjecture

Nagato (and his puppets) seems to have the Rinnegan up 24/7. In flashbacks to the Sage of Six Paths he has Rinnegan up so I believe it does not cause strain like the other ocular powers

Answer (score 0):

All *eye techniques* use up a lot of chakra.

Clan users can use the techniques for longer periods of time as compared to non clan users (like Kakashi). But even then there is a limit to which the doujutsu can be used, and that is dependent on the chakra level of the user.

Now to which extent the Rinnegan can be used has not been explicitly defined in the manga, so it can only be a guess. But surely it should cause strain to the user on over usage.

Comment: While I agree all ocular techniques use chakra, that doesn't necessarily mean they cause strain. Sasuke could probably keep on his normal 3 tomoe sharingan for the whole day and while it may consume chakra, I doubt it will strain his eyes. At this point, only using the mangekyou seem to do that. It seems pretty normal to always have rinnegan on, where as sharingan and byukagan get turned off, so it might cause no strain. This is all just speculation though.